# Where to attach hook and eye to prop a hinged casement window open?

Tags: windows, window-frame

My 100+ year old house has one original casement window that has no crank; it just opens on hinges. Which is annoying because the wind can blow it closed. I was visiting another old house and noticed they used a hook and eye to keep the window open. Seems like a good idea, so I bought some. But I could use some advice about where to attach the hook and the eye.

First, I'm assuming that the eye (not the hook) should be attached to the window so the hook won't hang down and prevent the window from closing. Furthermore, I'm assuming that the hook should be attached under the window on the outside sill (not on the inside sill) so that it's not in the way when it's not in use. Are these assumptions correct?

If yes, then does it matter where the eye is attached on the window and where the hook is attached on the outside sill? Or is any placement OK as long as, when hooked, the window is open the desired amount?

Here's a picture of the window with one possible placement.  (BTW, I know the sill needs to be painted!  We're actually getting it painted this week, which reminded me to figure out the hook and eye thing.)

[image]

Comment: It should work, but hooks have a bad habit of popping out of eyes, with little force(wind).  For a window that might slam, would prefer a positive mount.  Don't know the name, but two pieces of long metal(steel) with a pivot point hold them together, screw to window and frame.

Comment: Kind of like an opening mechanism for a casement window???  Though the window frame may have to be modified for something like that to fit.

Answer (score 2):

That looks terribly flimsy for a casement stay.

I don't know where in the world you may be, but in the UK casement stays are standard fare for that type of window. They come in a myriad different styles from plain to ornate, but are all basically the same principal. They're also simple to attach, especially on wood.

[image]

[Link to fairly random google searched online store](https://www.ironmongerydirect.co.uk/browse/window-furniture-and-hardware/casement-hardware/casement-stays-and-fasteners/filter/ironmongery_type%3E%7Bstays%7D)